# Registration of SPNs for Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, configuration, listener, spn

Manually registering SPNs for Availability group -

1. Do I need to register SPNs for the AG Listener **as well as the individual nodes**, for both the instance name and the listening ports for the managed service account? The application uses the Listener to connect, are SPNs required for the individual nodes if using Kerberos authentication?
2. Does the Listener name have to be same as the AG name?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server itself, given the appropriate permission in Active Directory, will automatically register SPNs for all names, including the virtual network name of any Availability Groups configured.

Based on that, I would say it's safe to say that you *should* manually register SPNs for the AG names.  It certainly won't hurt security, and will be one less thing to troubleshoot later.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes you should register SPNs for every listener names with and without domain name (fqdn) with and without port number or instance name in case of named instance.
2. no you can name the listener as you like

If you need it, review your configuration with this tool:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046